# How to choose third party dials before making a call in android

Tags: android, phone-call

I have implemented how to make a call in android, it working now but I need choose option before making call if any third party dials app is available in my phone, is it possible do this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "mobilePhone"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You want to display an dialog with a list of all dialing apps in the mob, before call?

Comment: Most phones come with a single dialer app.It would only ask if you had multiple dialer apps installed as I guess.

Comment: in my phone i have multi dialer , but it not asking before making a call

Answer (score 1):

As a measure of security android does not allow dialing app, i mean you can design your own dialing app and contacts etc but you can only go as far as "dialing the number", all calling etc is done by the system own app

if you want to build the app you need only call this

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:The telephone number to call")); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

After this android will take over control and make the call

Do not forget the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">
```

Comment: how to make a i know what am asking is it possible to open up available dialer befor making a call

Comment: As i said, as a security measure android does not allow for user to build dialing apps so thay will not provide selection menus or you to choose what app to use before dialing a number.

If you build an app that can make a call by using the intent system stated above, users will have to, by their own hand, go to your app to use it

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as answered with the checkmark on the left